# How to show one item value with autocomplete from jquery ui

Tags: jquery, search, input, autocomplete, onclick

i'm developing an input text search with autocomplete using post to get data:

```
$('#name_search').autocomplete({
  source: "search/name.php",
  open: function(){
     $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 1000);
        return false;
  }}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ){
     return $( "<li></li>" )
     .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
     .append( "<a>" + item.nome + "<br>" + item.cognome + "</a>" )
     .appendTo( ul );
};
```

It show me the two item inside the row of widget but when i click on it it will close itself and clear text inside input text.. what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

use the autocomplete's select method to define the value of the target input element.

```
    $('#name_search').autocomplete({
           source: "search/name.php",
           open: function(){
                  $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 1000);
                  return false;
            },
            select:function(event, ui){
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            }
      }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ){
     return $( "<li></li>" )
     .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
     .append( "<a>" + item.nome + "<br>" + item.cognome + "</a>" )
     .appendTo( ul );
};
```

source:

jquery ui autocomplete methods  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: nothing changes... when i click on widget the text inside input tag doesn't become the clicked text but it will be cleared

Comment: can you do console.log(ui) within the select method and post what is returned?

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding return false in select function:

```
$('#name_search').autocomplete({
            source: "search/name.php",
            open: function(){
                $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 1000);
                    return false;
            },
            select:function(event, ui){
                $(this).val(ui.item.nome+" - "+ui.item.cognome);
                return false;
            }
            }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ){
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.nome + "<br>" + item.cognome + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
```